# Using a Mobile Camera as a Barcode Scanner

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to create an app where I can use a phones camera to scan barcodes. I want to know how I would go about accessing the phones camera and how I would get the program to scan barcodes from the camera.

Comment: You can use New Google play services in which Barcode scan feature is already available and you can easily find sample on github

Answer (score 0):

The ZXing project provides a standalone barcode reader application which — via Android's intent mechanism — can be called by other applications who wish to integrate barcode scanning.

[This is a link to the project on github you'll find a sample app hope it helps](https://github.com/zxing/zxing)